# Group checkboxes do not show checked

Tags: javascript, dojo, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes and a toggle button to check/uncheck al checkboxes within      this group. The function associated with the button puts the value associated with each check box in another table. When the button is clicked, the function works fine, but the checkboxes do not display the check sign even when the button is clicked. Here is the code:

```
function selRemChecks(aDivId,buttonId){
    var myDiv = dojo.byId(aDivId).getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (j=0;j<myDiv.length;j++){
        myDiv[j].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].firstChild.checked=dojo.byId(buttonId).checked;
    }
    if (dojo.byId(buttonId).checked==true){
        dijit.byId(buttonId).set("label", "Clear group");
    }
    else if (dojo.byId(buttonId).checked==false){
        dijit.byId(buttonId).set("label", "Select group");
    }
}
```

Please suggest me a solution.

I have added my HTML code here:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" id="group1AForm" name="group1AForm">
<div dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" id="group1A" title="Population projection" open="false">
<table id="popIndTableA">
<tr id="testing">
<td id="indCBRA">Crude Birth Rate</td>
<td id="testing2"><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="check1A" id="checkCBRA" name="checkCBRA" /></td>
<td id="infoCBRA"><img id="imgCBRA" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="indTestA1">Test 1</td>
<td><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="check1A" id="checkTestA1" name="checkTestA1" /></td>
<td id="infoTestA1"><img id="imgTestA1" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="indTestA2">Test 2</td>                
<td><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" class="check1A" id="checkTestA2" name="checkTestA2" /></td>
<td id="infoTestA2"><img id="imgTestA2" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div dojo-data-type="dijit.form.Form" id="selectGrp1A" name="selectGrp1A">
<button dojoType="dijit.form.ToggleButton" iconClass="dijitCheckBoxIcon" id="selGrp1A" onclick="selRemChecks('group1A',this.id); ">Select group </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML? Using `childNodes[x]` is a really bad idea, since any rearrangement of your HTML will break your function.

Comment: JavaScript relies on HTML; without your HTML we cannot provide any specific, or particularly useful or insightful, answers to solve your problem. Please, help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: Not sure how to paste my HTML code here. I have tried but failed

Comment: Paste HTML exactly the same way you pasted your JavaScript. For help with the editing/formatting using MarkDown, see the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/).

Comment: Finaly, added HTML code to the original message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try this:
http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/checkboxes.asp